# [meta-]decision problem about decidability of finite Hilbert-style axiomatic systems

Tags: lo.logic

Consider some arbitrary language $S$ written over a given (propositional) [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) with a finite collection of [finitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary) constructors, and consider a procedure that receives as input an arbitrary finite [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) $H$, that is, a finite number of axioms and inference rules over $S$.  Let $L_H$ be the **logic** inductively defined by $H$ as usual. Let $P_H$ be the [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) of ascertaining whether $L_H$ is a decidable logic, that is, deciding about the derivability from $H$ of formulas of $S$.

Is $P_H$ decidable?

(I suspect the answer is negative, and that one could somehow codify the Halting Problem in $P_H$.  Before further investigating the matter, I would be happy though to learn if some literature already exists on this subject.)

Comment: Consider semi-Thue systems.  For each one construct a Hilbert System.  I think from this you can get your undecidability result. Gerhard "Pretty Sure About Being Unsure" Paseman, 2015.12.03

Comment: @GerhardPaseman This is a good suggestion, surely as good as a translation of our problem into Wang tiles or to the Post correspondence problem. I was recently discussing the issue with colleagues by email, and one of them implied that this result was actually part of *mathematical folklore*. Nonetheless, I have so far failed to find published references to such a result, which would seem to constitute an important bridge between proof systems and automata theory.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you are looking for Post--Linial theorems.

Comment: Well noted, @KarelChvalovský. I am now checking the papers by [Yntema](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093957737) and by [Ihrig](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093958077) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

$P_H$ is not decidable.

The proof is just like the proof for halting problem.

We could just choose a programming language or similar things, e.g. combinatory logic, and encode $P_H$ into the language as a function.

We could define a set of inference rules $S$ :
$$ Eval(A,B) \over Eval(A,B') $$
where $A,B$ and $B'$ are expressions in the language, and $B'$ is $B$ after a step of evaluation. And
$$ Eval(A,\top) \over Eval(X,X) $$
where $\top$ is the expression of "true" in the language, $X$ could be any valid expression in the language. And
$$ Rules(R) \over Eval(P_H(R \cup \{{ \over Rules(R)}\}),P_H(R \cup \{{\over Rules(R)}\})) $$
where $R$ is a set of inference rules.

Deciding on $S\cup\{{ \over Rules(S)}\}$ in $P_H$ will lead to contradiction.